# Extraction of values with scope 'row' from html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <caption>Alien football stars</caption>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Player</th>
        <th scope="col">Gloobles</th>
        <th scope="col">Za'taak</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">TR-7</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>4,569</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Khiresh Odo</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7,223</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Mia Oolong</th>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6,219</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to extract all values from the 'Player' column. How can I do it?

I tried this way but it doesn't work in the proper way:

```
var table = $("#table tbody");

        table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                productId = $tds.eq(0).text();
        });
```

Comment: why are you trying to find `td` when `scope="row"` is on `th`? and why not use $("scope='row']") selector?

Comment: As observed above, you are trying to find `td` in the row, but the data you want is in a `th` - change td to th and it'll work:  `$(this).find("th").eq(0).text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues: `"#table"` id does not exist, you are selecting `td`, when your data is in `th`, you forgot to push data to array.

You can use attribute selector `[scope='row']` to get players data.

```js
var table = $("table");
var players = [];
table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
 var $tds = $(this).find("[scope='row']");
  if($tds.length>0){
      productId = $tds.eq(0).text();
     players.push( productId);
  }
});


console.log(players);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <caption>Alien football stars</caption>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Player</th>
        <th scope="col">Gloobles</th>
        <th scope="col">Za'taak</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">TR-7</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>4,569</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Khiresh Odo</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7,223</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Mia Oolong</th>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6,219</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can use 'map' method like this for shorter syntax:

```js
const players = $("table [scope='row']").map((index, el) => $(el).text()).get();
console.log(players)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <caption>Alien football stars</caption>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Player</th>
        <th scope="col">Gloobles</th>
        <th scope="col">Za'taak</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">TR-7</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>4,569</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Khiresh Odo</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7,223</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Mia Oolong</th>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6,219</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```